# Adding TabItems dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` control

```
<TabControl Name="Farms_myVillages"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Villages}">
</TabControl/>
```

In the code behind I add some tabs dynamically to the `TabControl` as follows:

```
foreach (Village vill in Villages)
{
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();
    tab.Header = vill.Name;
    VillageUserControl c = new VillageUserControl();
    c.DataContext = vill;
    tab.Content = c;
    Farms_myVillages.Items.Add(tab);
}
```

where `VillageUserControl` is a `UserControl` that deal with the specified village. This code works fine and it gets the expected results...

The problem is that I don't want this to be in the code behind but just in the `xaml` itself.

I try this:

```
<TabControl Name="Farms_myVillages"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Villages}">
      <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="TabItem">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
              <Setter Property="Content">
                 <Setter.Value>
                    <u:VillageUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                 </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>
      </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

After I run it, it throws an exception: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

Did I miss something? Please help me here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You set the wrong thing, you should not modify the [`ItemContainerStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) but the [`TabControl.ItemTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for the header and [`TabControl.ContentTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) for the content.

*(The exception may have to do with the fact that in the style only one `VillageUserControl` is created, but the style applies to multiple tab items.)*

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped :) (On a side note: You can mark answers via the checkmark outline that appears if you move your mouse below the votes on the left, so far you have not accepted any answers to your questions, you might want to go through them and accept the answer that helped the most)

Answer (score 3):

Now it is working:

```
<TabControl Name="Farms_myVillages" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Villages}">
       <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <u:VillageResources/>
            </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of not having this in code behind is right, instead of using `ItemContainerStyle` use `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate`. You can have a look at this sample from Josh Smith for creating a tabs using Templates and Styles -

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026