# wpf button click event

Tags: wpf, datacontext, observablecollection

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720446/wpf-adding-tabitems-dynamically/4722047#4722047) I asked about adding `TabItems` dynamically to a `TabControl`
the `ItemsSource` are from `ObservableCollection<Village>`..
My question is if added a button to any `TabItem`, this button will have the `DataContext` of its container `TabItem`, how could I implement the Click event for this button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have added the Button to the DataTemplate, then on your Button_Click method you can easily get the 'Village' datacontext.

```
    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Village clickedVillage = ((Button)sender).DataContext as Village;
        //Do whatever you want to do with the Village
    }
```

But again, the above solution is not the best way to go for this problem. MVVM pattern would expect a ICommand in your Village (Or its container class) and you will bind that command to the Button.Command property so there wont be any code-behind at all. Or in other words your XAML will be more cleaner and ViewModel will get more self-contained in terms of properties and actions.