# add tabitem to tabcontrol in window from a usercontrol Button click

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have a tabcontrol in a Window and a userconrol in the same window and i want to add a tabitem in tabcontrol on a button click which is in usercontrol so how to do this ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589298/how-to-add-wpf-page-to-tabcontrol and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720446/adding-tabitems-dynamically

Comment: Try posting your code which you have tried and problem you are facing in that code here.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that the button is in the user control and the tabControl is in the window, I think you need to set an event in your user control that fires when the userscontrol handels the button's click event internally, so you can handle the click from outside.
at the handler you add the tab item dynamically.

C# code here is quite the same as I imagined: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33874/Capture-Button-s-Click-Event-of-User-Control-in-th

Comment: i want to add tabitem in tabcontrol which is in mainwindow from userControl'button . mainwindow contains both tabcontrol and the usercontrol .

Comment: I updated my answer @user2927844 sounds logical, but didn't test it